# XSLT - how to test condition expressed in external XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is (the relevant part of) my XML template file (referred to below as `template.xml'):

```
<Template>
  <ObjTmplId>74</ObjTmplId>
  <AttTmplId>312</AttTmplId>
  <Condition>Test=52</Condition>
</Template>

<Template>
  <ObjTmplId>58</ObjTmplId>
  <AttTmplId>100</AttTmplId>
  <Condition>TestTwo=21 or TestTwo=26</Condition>
</Template>

<Template>
  <ObjTmplId>8</ObjTmplId>
  <AttTmplId>10</AttTmplId>
  <Condition>TestThree!=1 or TestThree!=6</Condition>
</Template>
```

and here is my XML input:

```
<p:objectAttributes>
<p:attribute name="Test">10</p:attribute>
<p:attribute name="TestTwo">0</p:attribute>
<p:attribute name="TestThree">27</p:attribute>
</p:objectAttributes>
```

My current XSLT is this:

```
<xsl:when test="document('template.xml')
                /template/object/attribute/@name">
  <xsl:for-each select="document('template.xml')/condition">
    <xsl:element name="output:{@name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
```

How do I transform the XML input document using the template shown above, based on the condition expressed in the `<Condition>` element in the relevant template in `template.xml'?

Comment: It is not enough information that you were "not able to". Add your XSLT code to the question and we'll gladly point out where you went wrong.

Comment: I have added the xml input file

Comment: An XML document was _already_ there. Now you have added a second one, instead of showing XSLT code. The first sample you show is _not_ XSLT code, it's another form of XML.

Comment: I have also added the xslt but couldn't find a way to evaluate  <Condition>TestThree!=1 or TestThree!=6</Condition> in the xslt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a sanity check to make sure I have understood your question.

If I understand your question correctly, you want your XSLT to evaluate conditions which are not written into the XSLT itself as XPath expressions, but which are written in the `Condition` elements of an external 'template file', in a language which is not quite XPath.

For example (if I understand you correctly), on the given input the condition `Test=52` should evaluate to false, given that the input has

```
<p:attribute name="Test">10</p:attribute>
```

The condition `TestTwo=21 or TestTwo=26` should also evaluate to false, since the input has

```
<p:attribute name="TestTwo">0</p:attribute>
```

The condition `TestThree!=1 or TestThree!=6` will evaluate to true, because the input has

```
<p:attribute name="TestThree">27</p:attribute>
```

Note that for any integer value we assume for TestThree, this condition will always evaluate to true, since no matter what value is assumed for `TestThree`, that value will never be equal both to 1 and to 6, so it will always be unequal to one or the other.  The condition makes sense only if we assume some definition of equality that would allow a value to be equal both to 1 and to 6.  The = operator of XPath 2.0 provides such a definition of equality; if we assume XPath semantics for =, then the third Condition in your template file will evaluate to true just in case the value of TestThree is a sequence containing both 1 and 6.

---

If I've understood your question correctly, then your problem is that you want to write an interpreter for your Condition expressions using XSLT.  That's potentially a really interesting task.  But judging by the fragment of XSLT you give, I guess that you are a novice at XSLT, and that writing an interpreter in XSLT even for a simple expression language is a task you're not ready to undertake at the moment.  If it were me, I'd re-think the XML representation of the data and the logic of the transformation -- the level of indirection you're building into the data is going to make everything much much more complicated than it needs to be.

Some notes on your XSLT, not directly related to the question you ask, but directly related to your ability to make progress on this or any XSLT work:

- The condition on your `xsl:when` element reads

  ```
  document('template.xml')
  /template/object/attribute/@name
  ```

  This will never evaluate to true, since it cannot match anything in the `template.xml` you show (unless you omitted much more than just the wrapper element enclosing all the Template elements):  the document spells the element `Template`, not `template`, and the `Template` element has no children named `object`.

  From the general logic of the situation, I'd expect the test on the when element to relate to the main input, not the template.xml document.  So I guess that the leading call to the document() function is an error.  But the main input also has nothing that could possibly match the path expression `/template/object/attribute/@name`.  You have element name problems, you have namespace problems, and until you address them you're not going to be able to make anything at all work.
- The select on the xsl:for-each reads

  ```
  document('template.xml')/condition
  ```

  Again this will match nothing:  in the template document, the condition element spells its name with a capital C, not a lowercase C, and it's not the root element of the document.
- Inside the for-each, you have an xsl:element and specify its name as

  ```
  output:{@name}
  ```

  Since the context node when this is evaluated must necessarily have the name `condition`, this is going to look for a `name` attribute on a `condition` element -- you haven't shown us any elements named condition, and the elements you have shown named Condition don't have `name` attributes.

I think you might benefit from systematic study of a good XSLT book.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 A very generous answer, given that the question does not explain much!